# How to set first controller data another controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**Here I added categoryCtrl and ProductCtrl. This code line** `console.log(category);` **is working properly. How to bind this data for the product controller using for loop or whatever.**

```
.controller('CategoryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.playlists = {};

    $http.get("http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shop-categorylist-product.php").then(function(response) {
      vm.playlists = response.data.category;
      console.log(response.data.category);
    });


    $scope.selectedJsonObject=function(category){
        console.log(category);
    } 

})
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams)  {

});
```

Comment: Create one `service` which will be responsible for sharing data between angular components.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass Datas either Rootscope or Factories or services

**JS using factory**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="project">
<head>
    <title>Angular: Service example</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script>
var projectModule = angular.module('project',[]);
projectModule.factory('theService', function() {  
  var data ={}
  data.x ={}
    return data;
});
function FirstCtrl($scope, theService) {
  console.log(theService)

    $scope.name = "First Controller datas";
    theService.x =  $scope.name ;
}
function SecondCtrl($scope, theService) {   
    $scope.someThing = theService.x; 
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        <h2> Second Controller recives {{someThing}}</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to add these example in my project my friend

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.selectedJsonObject=function(category){
    console.log(category);
$scope.$emit('eventName', { message: category});
}
```

and in your productctrl
use

```
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams)  {
 $scope.$on('eventName', function (event, args) {


$scope.message = args.message;
 console.log($scope.message);});
});
```

Comment: Creating a service is more clean, testable and reusable solution then propagation event through your application for this purpose.

Comment: maybe you are right but it is more efficient and easy way and moreover this $on and $broadcast is also testable.

Comment: .controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var vm = this;    vm.playlists = {};$http.get("http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shop-categorylist-product.php").then(function(response) {
      vm.playlists = response.data.category;console.log(response.data.category);
    })$scope.selectedJsonObject=function(category{console.log(category);$scope.$broadcast('eventName', { message: category});
 }})
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams)  {$scope.$on('eventName', function (event, args) {$scope.message = args.message;console.log($scope.message);
 });});

Answer (score 0):

i fix your code, using a service should be a  correct solution.

```
.controller('CategoryCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.playlists = myService.playList;    
    $scope.selectedJsonObject=function(category){
        console.log(category);
    } 

})
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, myService)  {
  this.playlists = myService.playList;
});

.service('myService', function($http){
    var playlist = {};
    $http.get("http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shop-categorylist-product.php").then(function(response) {
      playlist = response.data.category;
      console.log(response.data.category);
    });

   this.playList = function(){
     return playList;
   }

});
```

Comment: `Can't find variable: $http` will show this error in console my friend

Comment: I have to add this service file separate or in same controller my friend

Comment: you have to inject $http inside the service, i fixed the code. you can put everything in the same file or in separate files