# How to set console data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Below this code console.log is working properly. How to set this data another page using another controller.

```
$scope.selectedJsonObject=function(category)
{
 console.log(category);
}
```

Comment: use a service to communicate between controllers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563874/how-to-set-first-controller-data-another-controller/38564637#38564637 

This is my full question my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Service`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to share the variable across two controllers,

```
angular.module('Shared', []);
angular.module("Shared").factory("myService", function(){
  return {sharedObject: {data: "eran" } }
});
angular.module('Shared').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
  $scope.myVar = myService.sharedObject;
});
angular.module('Shared').controller('Secondtrl', function($scope, $http, myService) {
  $scope.myVar = myService.sharedObject;
});
```

Working [`App`](http://jsfiddle.net/z3taxscp/2/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563874/how-to-set-first-controller-data-another-controller/38564637#38564637 

This is my full question

Comment: @DRK apply the same on your app